# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isRequired' of undefined at @material-ui/...../ClickAwayListener/

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Its throwing following error on console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property isRequired of undefined at Module../node_modules/@material-ui/core/esm/ClickAwayListener/ClickAwayListener.js (ClickAwayListener.js:109)
```

and throws following warning during compilation:

```
export 'elementAcceptingRef' was not found in '@material-ui/utils'
```

On checking the elementAcceptingRef.js in @material-ui/utils there is just a simple js file ending with exports.default = _default;

I am not sure how to resolve this issue.

**EDIT1:**
Bug raised on Material UI repo
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/16830#event-2522939273

**EDIT2:**

`componet.js`

```
import { Popover } from '@material-ui/core/'
import classnames from 'classnames'
import React from 'react'
import { withStyles } from '../styles/'
import { popoverStyles } from './styles'


const MYPopover = withStyles(popoverStyles)(class extends React.Component {

    static displayName = 'MYPopover'

    static propTypes = Popover.propTypes

    render() {

        const { props } = this

        return (
            <Popover {...{
                ...props,
                className: classnames('my-popover', props.className)
            }} />
        )
    }
})

export default MYPopover
```

Comment: You can try to reinstall *material-ui* using `npm install @material-ui/core` or `yarn add @material-ui/core`

Comment: @Fraction Yes i already tried it multiple times but no result.

Comment: Can you share the component that causes the error ?

Comment: Added the component

Comment: have you tried to debug the ClickAwayListener.js line 109 ?